# Better way to check if a string has a value from a list of strings

Tags: javascript, string

There is a list of strings and I want to check if the one I check has a value from there.

For example, the list is `"good", "amazing", "bad", "better", "worse"`

and this function:

```
checkPositive = (str) => {
  if(str === "good" || str === "amazing" || str === "better") {
      return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```

My question is if it's possible to do it more efficiently than it is now, I don't like how that `if` statement looks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an array and `.includes`:

```
checkPositive = str => ['good', 'amazing', 'better'].includes(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Build a dictionary:

```
let dict={
        good:  true
      , amazing: true
      , better: true
    };

checkPositive = str => { return dict[str]; } // dict[str] ? true : false, if you need actual boolean values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` which will return `-1` is the string is not present in list(assuming it is an array)

```js
const strList = ["good", "amazing", "bad", "better", "worse"]

checkPositive = (str) => {
  return strList.indexOf(str) !== -1 ? true : false;
}

console.log(checkPositive('good')) // true;
console.log(checkPositive('hello')) // true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`Regular_Expressions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) as well to check the particular string

```js
const checkPositive = str => /good|amazing|better/.test(str.toLowerCase());

console.log(`For bad ` +checkPositive('bad'));
console.log(`For amazing `+checkPositive('amazing'));
```